# How to only share stats for a specific URL?

Tags: google-analytics, adsense

So I know it's possible to see analytics stats on a specific URL but is it possible to only share stats on specific URLs to other people through permissions?

Preferably I'd like to do this in Adsense so others can see how much revenue that URL generated, but if thats not possible being able to share URL specific stats in Analytics is also fine.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a data view that excludes all but the desired URL and give access only to that. You could also create something via the Core Reporting API (which would be programming and makes this tenuously on-topic. But it would be easier than API programming (and more economically than creating a view, as the number of views is limited) to create a report in [Google Data Studio](https://datastudio.google.com/) (which is free) that filters by that single URL and then share it (with just reading rights).